# NTFS Permissions Report

Tags: powershell, ntfs

I am trying to run the below script to get a report of all file permissions on a shared drive:

```
$FolderPath = Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path "\\cst-fileserver\Company" -Recurse -Force 
$Output = @() 
ForEach ($Folder in $FolderPath) {     $Acl = Get-Acl -Path $Folder.FullName     
  ForEach ($Access in $Acl.Access) { 
    $Properties = [ordered]@{'Folder Name'=$Folder.FullName;'Group/User'=$Access.IdentityReference;'Permissions'=$Access.FileSystemRights;'Inherited'=$Access.IsInherited} 
    $Output += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $Properties             
  } 
} $Output | Out-GridView } $Report | Export-Csv -path "C:\new\FolderPermissions.csv"`
```

I get the below error when attempting this and I am fairly new with powershell so unsure how to troubleshoot this best.

```bash
Get-ChildItem : Could not find a part of the path 'D:\\shares\\Company\\2MPTRegulatory\\REGULATORY\\PLPI\\PLPI GRANTED\\MPT\\0883 COO(0168) Pulmicort Turbohaler 200 PL\\0883 Granted docs - take
effect from 19-06-18\\CST0168 archive\\0168 Pulmicort Turbohaler 200 PL\\sample scans-checks\\CST0168 Polish Pulmicort Turbuhaler 200ug 100doses (90x38x38) 23.06.2014'.
At line:1 char:15

+ ... olderPath = Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path "D:\\shares" -Recurse -Forc ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  + CategoryInfo          : ReadError: (D:\\shares\\Compa...x38) 23.06.2014:String) \[Get-ChildItem\], DirectoryNotFoundException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

Get-ChildItem : Could not find a part of the path 'D:\\shares\\Company\\2MPTRegulatory\\REGULATORY\\PLPI\\PLPI GRANTED\\MPT\\0883 COO(0168) Pulmicort Turbohaler 200 PL\\0883 Granted docs - take
effect from 19-06-18\\CST0168 archive\\0168 Pulmicort Turbohaler 200 PL\\sample scans-checks\\CST0168 Polish Pulmicort Turbuhaler 200ug 100doses (BUYER) 23.09.2015'.
At line:1 char:15

+ ... olderPath = Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path "D:\\shares" -Recurse -Forc ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  + CategoryInfo          : ReadError: (D:\\shares\\Compa...YER) 23.09.2015:String) \[Get-ChildItem\], DirectoryNotFoundException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

Get-ChildItem : Could not find a part of the path 'D:\\shares\\Company\\2MPTRegulatory\\REGULATORY\\PLPI\\PLPI GRANTED\\MPT\\0883 COO(0168) Pulmicort Turbohaler 200 PL\\0883 Granted docs - take
effect from 19-06-18\\CST0168 archive\\0168 Pulmicort Turbohaler 200 PL\\sample scans-checks\\CST0168 Pulmicort Turbohaler 200mcg 100 doses PL(88x38x38) 26.10.16'.
At line:1 char:15

+ ... olderPath = Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path "D:\\shares" -Recurse -Forc ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  + CategoryInfo          : ReadError: (D:\\shares\\Compa...38x38) 26.10.16:String) \[Get-ChildItem\], DirectoryNotFoundException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

Answer (score 0):

Those file name paths are [too long](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=registry) for windows.

It depends a little, but you can usually get around this with longer path name format: `\\?\` like:

```bash
Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path '\\?\D:\shares\Company\'
# Or for network paths:
Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path '\\?\UNC\cst-fileserver\Company'
```

It will work for powershell and `Get-Acl` But be aware that some software still won't allow paths that long